# Ansible: Skips "always" tags in roles

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which calls multiple roles I have written. This playbook has each role tagged so than I can call them separately or run the entire procedure from start to end. Within the roles additional tags may be provided to break up the works within those as well. Some of the role tasks are tagged with "always" because I want them to execute whenever the role is ran, regardless of any role specific tags.

The problem I am running into is that these "always" tags execute whether the role specific tag is called or not. If I don't call the tag for a role, I don't want to role to execute at all, including any "always" tasks specific to that role.

Example:

```
# Playbook
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: roleA
      tags: do_roleA

    - role: roleB
      tags: do_roleB


# Role A: 
- name: Always do this when doing role A
  debug: msg="test"
  tags: always

- name: Task1
  debug: msg="task1"
  tags: do_task1

- name: Task2
  debug: msg="task2"
  tags: do_task2
```

Example call:

```
ansibile-playbook my-playbook.yml --tags "do_roleB"
```

But this causes the debug in Role A to occur as well.

Some requirements I have:

- Can not skip "always" as roleB may have some tasks that require it.
- Do not want to change the tag from always and add a list of tags for every sub task. i.e. [do_task1,do_task2] as the number of tags would become large and easy to forget to add one.

Basically I am looking for a way to tell Ansible, if I call a "playbook tag" execute only roles from the playbook where the tag matches; do not execute any of the tasks in roles that do not match, even if they are tagged with "always". But if I call a "role tag" execute all the tasks in that role which either have tags of "always" or the tag I called.

Does Ansible have a feature like this? If it helps I am using Ansible 2.0.1.0

Comment: Can you give a try with: ansibile-playbook my-playbook.yml –skip-tags "do_roleA"

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that applying tag `do_roleA` to a role **adds** `do_roleA` tag to **every** task in that role.
So your example role actually becomes:

```
# Role A:
- name: Always do this when doing role A
  debug: msg="test"
  tags:
    - always
    - do_roleA

- name: Task1
  debug: msg="task1"
  tags:
    - do_task1
    - do_roleA

- name: Task2
  debug: msg="task2"
  tags:
    - do_task2
    - do_roleA
```

You can remove `always` tag from that task, so after tagging a role with `do_roleA` it will be the only tag for that task.
So calling playbook with `-t do_roleB` will not execute that task.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might land on this page having the same issue -- the solution is to use [`untagged`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags):

playbook.yaml

```yaml
- name: Preparing gateway node
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  serial: 1
  remote_user: root
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - include_role: 
        name: my-role
      tags: [ untagged, install, config, my-role-enable-service ]
```

my-role/tasks/main.yaml

```yaml
- name: Task 1
  debug:
    msg: "Run when tags: untagged and config"
  tags: [ untagged, config ]

- name: Task 2
  debug:
    msg: "Run when tags: untagged and install"
  tags: [ untagged, install ]

- name: Task 3 
  debug:
    msg: "Run when tags: my-role-enable-service"
  tags: [ untagged, my-role-enable-service ]
```

When you run:

1. `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml` -- runs all tasks
2. `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --tags config` -- runs only `Task 1`
3. `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --tags install` -- runs only `Task 2`
4. `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --tags my-role-enable-service` -- runs only `Task 3`

This quickly becomes handy when you have `all-in-one` roles that does installation or building from source in conjunction with configuration.

You can simply use `--tags config` after the installation steps have completed to speed-up your playbook instead of having to wait for things to build from sources every time.